# Get the value of radio button when the user clicks it

Tags: jquery

In a form I have 2 inputs where the 2nd input is filled automatically when the user fills the 1st one and then post them to server.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <select name="id" class="form-control" id="select" required> 
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">                      
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="car" required>
 </div>
</div>
```

and the script

```
var names = ${mylist} // I load here the list
$('#select').on('change keyup', function(e) {

  var i = this.selectedIndex;
  var txt = i ? names[i - 1] : '';
  var status=1;
  $('#inputName').val(txt);

  //Point1
  //here I post the i, txt, status to the server

});
```

It works fine. Now I added a radio input

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-4 >
    <div class="radio">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" required> 1</label>
        <label> <input type="radio" name="status" value="2" required> 2 </label>  
        <label> <input type="radio" name="status" value="3" required> 3 </label>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to send the value of `status` (instead of status=1) when the user clicks the radio button. I added this in //point1:

```
$("input:radio[name=status]").click(function() {
    status = $(this).val(); 
});
```

but it doesn't work..

Comment: `$("input[name=status]:checked").val();` try like this

Comment: close the `input` elements for radio buttons and try your code theres nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @pratikwebdev i think there is something wrong OP is **not selecting** the `checked radio button`. How to get the val of checked radio button then?

Comment: Also correctly close the `<div class="col-lg-4>` inside `"` to `<div class="col-lg-4">` and include event inside document ready function.

Comment: @guradio it is being referred inside an event for same radio button

Comment: @guradio My bad I thought problem was with event. But it seems OP wants to access value of radio button inside another function. Your comment answers OPs question. Nat95 Please update title of question what are you really looking for.

Comment: @Nat95 when do you want to send values? on dropdown value change or radio button change event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`:checked` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to get the value of `checkbox` element which is selected, also use `change` event

```
$("input:radio[name=status]").change(function() {
    status = $("input:radio[name=status]:checked").val(); 
});
```

```js
$("input:radio[name=status]").click(function() {
  var status = $("input:radio[name=status]:checked").val();
  snippet.log(status)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" required>1</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="2" required>2</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="3" required>3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler is correct and will give you value of clicked radio button. It may happened that DOM is not ready when handler code executes. To ensure DOM is ready, put your script inside `$(function(){..});` or `$(document).ready(function(){....});`

**Note** - You markup is incorrect for `<div class="col-lg-4 >`, put quotes after class value.

```js
$(function(){
    $("input:radio[name=status]").click(function() {
       status = $(this).val(); 
       alert(status);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-4" ><!-- correct html by puttin quotes after class value-->
    <div class="radio">
        <label> <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" required> 1</label>
        <label> <input type="radio" name="status" value="2" required> 2 </label>  
        <label> <input type="radio" name="status" value="3" required> 3 </label>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: need not to close input tag. it is self closing internally.